# Can I award myself a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I was just curious, let's say that I posted a question, then put a bounty on it, and then found the answer myself, could I then award that bounty back to myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No.

Comment: Panda is sad... **:(**

Comment: @ParanoidPanda You shouldn't be sad: otherwise you would never have collected any bounties!  Look at it from the other way: most people would offer a bounty and retract it immediately after they got an answer!

Comment: @Fabby: Good point! I just found this question, read it, thought it was stupid, then it told me `You can't vote for your own post` when I tried to downvote it! :D